# Uttara gita bhashya of Gaudapada

Tags: mahabharata, gita, gaudapada

[Uttara Gita](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/uttara-gita-IDK878/) is a famous text containing the conversation of Lord Kesava with Arjuna.

> Traditional scholars claim that the Uttara-Gita has taken as its
> source the Asvamedha Parva of the Mahabharata. However, in one chapter
> of the Bhisma Parva there is a section of approximately fifty slokas
> that is popularly known as the Gitasara. Much of this section bears a
> marked resemblance to the text of the Uttara-Gita.

The english translation of this work [is available](https://www.shankaracharya.org/uttara_gita.php) from many sources.

Gaudapada Acharya has written a commentary for this text. The [sanskrit text](https://archive.org/details/UttaraGitaWithCommentary/page/n45/mode/2up) of the commentary is available but is an English translation available? Portions of the english translation of this commentary are available but I am asking for the complete English translation.

Shankara has cited this work of his paramaguru in his bhashyas. For example, in bhagavad gita bhashya 13.13, he cites 1.7 of the bhashya. Swami Vidyaranya extensively cites this work in his Taittiriya Upaniṣad Dipika.

Comment: Where does Shankara cite Uttara Gita Bhasya? Can you give some places where he does so?

Comment: I only have Uttara Gita English without commentary sir. Its 3 Chapters

Comment: @Tezz I have edited the question to include this.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Thank you, sir. Yes, English translation of the original text is available online. I have edited the question to reflect this. I am looking for the english translation of the bhashya. In this, he clearly states that Siva is same as Vishnu.

Comment: @GIRIBLR Oh interesting! Thank you for the reference... I think this Uttara Gita is the same which talks about some mystic yogic things like Kundalini also....

Comment: @GIRIBLR can you cite where exactly swami vidyaranya cites uttara gita in taittriya upanishad dipika(shloka no. Or screenshot)