# Is uttara gita mentioned by any previous acharyas in their works?

Tags: scripture, commentary

Sources say it is mentioned in Taittriya upanishad dipika by vidyaranya. If anybody knows can you cite page no ?

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46396/uttara-gita-bhashya-of-gaudapada

Comment: @swiftpushkar can you cite page number of taittriya upanishad dipika?